# Sapper: Resources not found after deploying on Netlify

Tags: svelte, netlify, sapper

Running into a problem where some css and js files are not found after deploying to Netlify. Locally, all files are found and everything is working as expected.

### [image: Resources not found error]

You check out the deployed version here: https://affectionate-bhabha-5b5349.netlify.app/

Repo can be found here: https://github.com/basti-n/sapper-personal-website

Comment: Not getting any console errors on my end, unless you fixed it since asking the question then maybe something in your local setup is affecting things, have you tried a private/different browser?

Answer (score 0):

**I fixed it by resetting to a previous commit, and then cherry-pick all subsequent commits one-by-one**. The errors are now gone... given that the code is now essentially the same, I can't quite understand why there was the issue before.